# Error:(14, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/ThemeOverLay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar')

Tags: java, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I have faced this error

> Error:(14, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'theme' with value '@style/ThemeOverLay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar').
>   Here is my code:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverLay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >
```

Here is the picture
[Here is the picture][1]

Please, help me. Thanks

Comment: Put code here not only image

Comment: i have uploaded already. Can you help me?